# MS Excel: Multifilter / Check which strings are already present in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, column

I have two separate, big sets of data (+25k rows):

YEAR CCS KPF
YEAR MMS MS

[image: Screenshot here]

CCS and MMS each denote string variables. How can I identify, which string is in which list already? I want to get rid of redundancies and only keep strings, which are in MMS. I DO NOT want to drop duplicates, order also matters.

Thank you!

Comment: What you want is unclear (to me, at least). Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1653315/edit) to provide the expected output, what you've tried and how it fails to reach the desired result?

Comment: Honestly I'm unable to identify the issue,, plz be specific & [edit] the post,,, the attached Screen Shot is insufficient to reflect the core issue !!

Comment: Did you have 2 tables?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by not dropping strings.  If you only want to identify the duplicates without dropping them, you could use Conditional formatting in each data set.  In the CCS column, create conditional formatting based on "Use a formula to determine which cells to format" and enter a formula that is something like this (customized to your sheets).

```
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( B2, CCS!$B$2:$B$7, 0 ) ) )
```

Likewise, in the CCS column, put the same conditional formatting on with a similar formula, perhaps like:

```
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( B2, MMS!$B$2:$B$7, 0 ) ) )
```

> Note that B2 must use relative address, not locked addressing and the
> ranges must be locked.  Also, both tables must be in the same workbook.

[image]

If you want to "get rid of redundancies and only keep strings, which are in MMS", it is not clear what you mean by "get rid of". You could manually delete the highlighted ones in CCS.  Also, the point about "order matters" is not clear in this context either.

The formula:

```
=NOT( ISNA( MATCH( B2, MMS!$B$2:$B$7, 0 ) ) )
```

could be added as a column called Duplicates on the CCS list along with a column of manually filled numbers (1,2,3...) with the header called SortKey.  Then you could sort by Duplicated and manually delete the duplicates in CCS and then resort it back using SortKey - then delete the SortKey column.